# Hiding the content of the particular Form tag in HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I wrote the following code, but it's not working. O want to hide the whole content of the parent `form` tag when I click the reject button:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()$('#reject').click(function()$(this).parent().find('form').hide();});   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="demo_form1">
        <legend>Form1</legend>
        <input value="Confirm"  type="button" id="confirm" />
    </form>

    <form  id="demo_form2">
        <legend>Form2</legend>
        <input value="Confirm"  type="button" id="confirm" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your code so we are able to read it and help you. And post only relevant parts.

Comment: I already changed it so it was able to read. But he changed it back.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing opening `{`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reject').click(function() { $(this).parent().find('form').hide(); }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is missing brackets.

And you need to use, because you don't want to search within your parent, your parent is the form tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reject').click(function(){
        $(this).parent("form").hide();
    });
});
```

Also you have 2 buttons with the same ID, which can't be used. jQuery will only search for the first ID it matches. Replace this with classes and it should be working for all buttons.